# Memory issue with foreach loop in R on Windows 8 (64-bit) (doParallel package)

Tags: r, memory, foreach, data.table

I'm trying to move from a serial to parallel approach to accomplish some multivariate time series analysis tasks on a large `data.table`.  The table contains data for many different groups and I'm trying to move from a `for` loop to a `foreach` loop using the `doParallel` package to take advantage of the multicore processor installed.

The problem I am experiencing relates to memory and how the new R processes seem to consume large quantities of it.  I think that what is happening is that the large `data.table` containing ALL data is copied into each new process, hence I run out of RAM and Windows starts swapping to disk.

I've created a simplified reproducible example which replicates my problem, but with less data and less analysis inside the loop.  It would be ideal if a solution existed which could only farm out the data to the worker processes on demand, or sharing the memory already used between cores.  Alternatively some kind of solution may already exist to split the big data into 4 chunks and pass these to the cores so they have a subset to work with.

A similar question has previously been posted [here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028452/reading-global-variables-using-foreach-in-r?lq=1) however I cannot make use of the `bigmemory` solution offered as my data contains a character field.  I will look further into the `iterators` package, however I'd appreciate any suggestions from members with experience of this problem in practice.

```
rm(list=ls())
library(data.table)
num.series = 40    # can customise the size of the problem (x10 eats my RAM)
num.periods = 200  # can customise the size of the problem (x10 eats my RAM)
dt.all = data.table(
    grp     = rep(1:num.series,each=num.periods), 
    pd      = rep(1:num.periods, num.series), 
    y       = rnorm(num.series * num.periods),
    x1      = rnorm(num.series * num.periods),
    x2      = rnorm(num.series * num.periods)
) 
dt.all[,y_lag := c(NA, head(y, -1)), by = c("grp")]

f_lm = function(dt.sub, grp) {
    my.model = lm("y ~ y_lag + x1 + x2 ", data = dt.sub)
    coef = summary(my.model)$coefficients
    data.table(grp, variable = rownames(coef), coef)
}

library(doParallel)  
registerDoParallel(4) 
foreach(grp=unique(dt.all$grp), .packages="data.table", .combine="rbind")  %dopar%
{
    dt.sub = dt.all[grp == grp]
    f_lm(dt.sub, grp)
}
detach(package:doParallel)
```

Comment: The statement dt.sub = dt.all[grp == grp] is going to cause a lot of copies of dt.sub to be floating around. Have you tried using the subset= argument of lm in your lm call to avoid having to do this? Also I'm wondering what is done with the return value of f_lm when it is calculated, it isn't assigned to anything.

Comment: Yes this example is flawed.  In reality I have to narrow down the possible formula for the upper and lower bound for `stepAIC`, filter out rows with `NA`s, obtain the best model, record coefficients, calculate elasticities and in-sample accuracy etc.  So there are a few steps in addition to just running `lm` and awkwardly I will be returning a list of `data.tables` to `foreach`.  I will certainly give `subset` some consideration, thanks for the suggestion.  I can handle copies of `dt.sub`, it's just `dt.all` that which can't have many copies in memory.

Comment: I'm surprised that multiple copies of dt.all would be created. According to the documentation for multicore "Modern operating systems use copy-on-write approach which makes this
so appealing for parallel computation since only objects modiﬁed during the computation will be
actually copied and all other memory is directly shared." I know dt.all would not reside in memory more than once on linux. Not sure about windows.

Comment: doParallel: "The multicore functionality supports multiple workers only on those operating systems that support the fork system call; this excludes Windows. By default, doParallel uses multicore
functionality on Unix-like systems and snow functionality on Windows".  I don't have documented evidence as to whether the data in the environment is copied but given that the packages required must be specified and I presume loaded into each instance of R then so would the data be required.  I guess it's a Windows thing.

Comment: Yes. I have been told this functionality works better on Unix (because of the fork command) but switching may not be an option for you.

Comment: Luckily it is an option as we have a Sun HPC cluster at the University but given my Unix knowledge and lack of experience of MPI/parallel I hoped to get things working on a smaller scale on the 64-bit Windows laptop first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterators can help to reduce the amount of memory that needs to be passed to the workers of a parallel program. Since you're using the data.table package, it's a good idea to use iterators and combine functions that are optimized for data.table objects.  For example, here is a function like `isplit` that works on data.table objects:

```
isplitDT <- function(x, colname, vals) {
  colname <- as.name(colname)
  ival <- iter(vals)
  nextEl <- function() {
    val <- nextElem(ival)
    list(value=eval(bquote(x[.(colname) == .(val)])), key=val)
  }
  obj <- list(nextElem=nextEl)
  class(obj) <- c('abstractiter', 'iter')
  obj
}
```

Note that it isn't completely compatible with `isplit`, since the arguments and return value are slightly different.  There may also be a better way to subset the data.table, but I think this is more efficient than using `isplit`.

Here is your example using `isplitDT` and a combine function that uses `rbindlist` which combines data.tables faster than `rbind`:

```
dtcomb <- function(...) {
  rbindlist(list(...))
}

results <- 
  foreach(dt.sub=isplitDT(dt.all, 'grp', unique(dt.all$grp)),
          .combine='dtcomb', .multicombine=TRUE,
          .packages='data.table') %dopar% {
    f_lm(dt.sub$value, dt.sub$key)
  }
```

---

*Update*

I wrote a new iterator function called `isplitDT2` which performs much better than `isplitDT` but requires that the data.table have a key:

```
isplitDT2 <- function(x, vals) {
  ival <- iter(vals)
  nextEl <- function() {
    val <- nextElem(ival)
    list(value=x[val], key=val)
  }
  obj <- list(nextElem=nextEl)
  class(obj) <- c('abstractiter', 'iter')
  obj
}
```

This is called as:

```
setkey(dt.all, grp)
results <-
  foreach(dt.sub=isplitDT2(dt.all, levels(dt.all$grp)),
          .combine='dtcomb', .multicombine=TRUE,
          .packages='data.table') %dopar% {
    f_lm(dt.sub$value, dt.sub$key)
  }
```

This uses a binary search to subset `dt.all` rather than a vector scan, and so is more efficient. I don't know why `isplitDT` would use more memory, however. Since you're using `doParallel`, which doesn't call the iterator on-the-fly as it sends out tasks, you might want to experiment with splitting `dt.all` and then removing it to reduce your memory usage:

```
dt.split <- as.list(isplitDT2(dt.all, levels(dt.all$grp)))
rm(dt.all)
gc()
results <- 
  foreach(dt.sub=dt.split,
          .combine='dtcomb', .multicombine=TRUE,
          .packages='data.table') %dopar% {
    f_lm(dt.sub$value, dt.sub$key)
  }
```

This may help by reducing the amount of memory needed by the master process during the execution of the foreach loop, while still only sending the required data to the workers. If you still have memory problems, you could also try using doMPI or doRedis, both of which get iterator values as needed, rather than all at once, making them more memory efficient.

Comment: Nice solution Steve, especially the combination function and the generic nature of the solution, thanks. Unfortunately I don't get to accept my own answer as this one is clearly better!

Comment: I tried using this approach on my real data and it caused the laptop to  run out of memory.  Same issue on the cluster with 10GB RAM.  So I tested both solutions against the original problem specification and was surprised to find that the `system.time` comparison was 49s for `isplitDT` with `dtcomb` against 14.76s for the basic `isplit` with `rbind`. So I ran 4 tests to evaluate the combinations of `rbind`/`rbindlist` x `isplit`/`isplitDT`.  This pointed to the slowdown being due to `isplitDT` as opposed to `rbindlist`.  Will post test code if reqd.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

The answer requires the `iterators` package and use of `isplit` which is similar to `split` in that it breaks the main data object into chunks based on one or more `factor` columns.  The `foreach` loop iterates through the chunks of data, passing only the subset out to the worker process rather than the whole table.

So the differences in the code are as follows:

```
library(iterators)
dt.all = data.table(
    grp     = factor(rep(1:num.series, each  =num.periods)),  # grp column is a factor
    pd      = rep(1:num.periods, num.series), 
    y       = rnorm(num.series * num.periods),
    x1      = rnorm(num.series * num.periods),
    x2      = rnorm(num.series * num.periods)
) 

results = 
    foreach(dt.sub = isplit(dt.all, dt.all$grp), .packages="data.table", .combine="rbind")  
    %dopar%
    {
        f_lm(dt.sub$value, dt.sub$key[[1]])
    }
```

The result of the `isplit` is that `dt.sub` is now a `list` with 2 elements: the `key` is in itself a list of the values used to split and the `value` contains the subset as a `data.table`.

Credit for this solution is given to a [SO answer given by David](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395191/how-to-split-a-data-frame-by-rows-and-then-process-the-blocks) and a response by Russell to my question on an [excellent blog post about iterators](http://www.exegetic.biz/blog/2013/11/iterators-in-r/#comment-18274).

------------------------------------ EDIT ------------------------------------

To test the performance of `isplitDT` v `isplit` and `rbindlist` v `rbind` the following code was used:

```
rm(list=ls())
library(data.table) ; library(iterators)  ;   library(doParallel)
num.series = 400
num.periods = 2000
dt.all = data.table(
    grp     = factor(rep(1:num.series,each=num.periods)), 
    pd      = rep(1:num.periods, num.series), 
    y       = rnorm(num.series * num.periods),
    x1      = rnorm(num.series * num.periods),
    x2      = rnorm(num.series * num.periods)
)
dt.all[,y_lag := c(NA, head(y, -1)), by = c("grp")]

f_lm = function(dt.sub, grp) {
    my.model = lm("y ~ y_lag + x1 + x2 ", data = dt.sub)
    coef = summary(my.model)$coefficients
    data.table(grp, variable = rownames(coef), coef)
}

registerDoParallel(8)

isplitDT <- function(x, colname, vals) {
  colname <- as.name(colname)
  ival <- iter(vals)
  nextEl <- function() {
    val <- nextElem(ival)
    list(value=eval(bquote(x[.(colname) == .(val)])), key=val)
  }
  obj <- list(nextElem=nextEl)
  class(obj) <- c('abstractiter', 'iter')
  obj
}

dtcomb <- function(...) {
  rbindlist(list(...))
}

# isplit/rbind
st1 = system.time(results <- foreach(dt.sub=isplit(dt.all,dt.all$grp),   
                    .combine="rbind",
                    .packages="data.table")  %dopar% {
    f_lm(dt.sub$value, dt.sub$key[[1]])
})
# isplit/rbindlist
st2 = system.time(results <- foreach(dt.sub=isplit(dt.all,dt.all$grp),  
                .combine='dtcomb', .multicombine=TRUE,
                .packages="data.table") %dopar% {
    f_lm(dt.sub$value, dt.sub$key[[1]])
})
# isplitDT/rbind
st3 = system.time(results <- foreach(dt.sub=isplitDT(dt.all, 'grp',     unique(dt.all$grp)),
            .combine='dtcomb', .multicombine=TRUE,
            .packages='data.table') %dopar% {
    f_lm(dt.sub$value, dt.sub$key)
})
# isplitDT/rbindlist
st4 = system.time(results <- foreach(dt.sub=isplitDT(dt.all, 'grp', unique(dt.all$grp)),
                .combine='dtcomb', .multicombine=TRUE,
                .packages='data.table') %dopar% {
    f_lm(dt.sub$value, dt.sub$key)
  })

rbind(st1, st2, st3, st4)
```

This gives the following timings:

```
    user.self sys.self elapsed user.child sys.child
st1     12.08     1.53   14.66         NA        NA
st2     12.05     1.41   14.08         NA        NA
st3     45.33     2.40   48.14         NA        NA
st4     45.00     3.30   48.70         NA        NA
```

------------------------------------ EDIT 2 ------------------------------------

Thanks to Steve's updated answer and the function `isplitDT2`, which makes use of the keys on the `data.table`, we have a clear new winner in terms of speed.  Running `microbenchmark` to compare my original solution (in this answer) shows around 7-fold improvement from `isplitDT2` with `rbindlist`.  Memory usage has not yet been compared directly but the performance gain leads me to accept the answer at last.

Comment: Did isplitDB2 from my updated answer do better either in speed or memory use?

Comment: @SteveWeston: thanks for the update which performs considerably better on the toy example in the question. I'll try it now on the real dataset and assess memory usage too.

Answer (score 2):

Holding everything in memory is one of those (aargh, annoying) things that `R` programmers have to learn to deal with. It's pretty easy to imagine your code example as either memory-bound or CPU-bound, and you'll need to figure that out before trying to apply workarounds.

Assuming the memory is being consumed by your dataset (`dt_all`) and not during the actual model run, it is possible you might be able to release enough memory for the worker processes to parallelize:

```
foreach(grp=unique(dt.all$grp), .packages="data.table", .combine="rbind")  %dopar%
{
    dt.sub = dt.all[grp == grp]
    rm(dt.all)
    gc()
    f_lm(dt.sub, grp)
}
```

However, this assumes that your working set (`dt.sub`) is small enough that you can fit more than one of them in memory at a time. It isn't hard to imagine a problem set too large for that. Also, and this is really annoying, all the workers are going to fire up at one time and kill your machine anyway, so you might need to make them pause for a couple seconds to allow other children to load up and release memory.

Though desperately stupid and brute-force, I have handled this exact problem by writing the subsets out to disk as individual data files, and then used a batch script to run my computations in parallel.

Comment: Very good point regarding deleting the `dt.all` and the phasing of child loads!  Luckily my `dt.sub` isn't so huge (313 x 100) as to consume tonnes of memory.  Writing to disk would be an option as you  suggest, I'll test it tomorrow.  Currently I'm toying with parallel computing on my laptop, in production I'll be able to use the University HPC so should be able to use more memory and nodes when I understand what I'm doing!

Comment: If your working set is manageable, your major issue is likely to be the trade-off between time to create the subset and time to run the model. That trade-off will likely dictate your approach. GL!

Comment: Removing dt.all will cause an error if the number of tasks is greater than the number of workers, since tasks will start to fail when any worker executes a subsequent task.  This is an even bigger problem when using the default doSEQ backend, since the master's copy is removed after executing the first task.